The "Active Material" window is constantly opened with the left mouse button in all modes. How to remove it?
The "Active Material" window is constantly opened with the left mouse button in all modes. How to remove it?
I tried reinstalling the program.


I would go to your Prefs under Keymaps and at the top you'll see "Key Binding"; type in "Left Mouse" to show all keymaps that use LMB and see if there's a random one out of place like "Active material edit" or something and delete it with the X on the right. You probably right clicked > add shortcut and then clicked with the LMB on accident setting that Keymap to be LMB.
